# React Navigation not working with Firebase in React Native App

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I have a funny problem.

When I press sign-up button, the function below is called in SignUp component.

```
//SignUp.js
signUpHandler = () => {
        if (this.state.email == '' || this.state.password == '') {
            alert("Email or Password is empty.")
        }
        else {
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
                .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ExtendedRegisteration'))
                .catch(error => { alert(error.message) });
        }
    }
```

Now this doesn't navigate to "ExtendedRegisteration" but when I do the below, it navigates just fine.

```
//SignUp.js
signUpHandler = () => {
        if (this.state.email == '' || this.state.password == '') {
            alert("Email or Password is empty.")
        }
        else {
                this.props.navigation.navigate('ExtendedRegisteration')
        }
    }
```

Is this a problem with Firebase? 
I need to navigate to "ExtendedRegisteration" after I signup using firebase.

Output from this.props in signUpHandler :

```
Object {
  "navigation": Object {
    "addListener": [Function addListener],
    "canGoBack": [Function canGoBack],
    "dangerouslyGetParent": [Function dangerouslyGetParent],
    "dangerouslyGetState": [Function anonymous],
    "dispatch": [Function dispatch],
    "goBack": [Function anonymous],
    "isFocused": [Function isFocused],
    "jumpTo": [Function anonymous],
    "navigate": [Function anonymous],
    "pop": [Function anonymous],
    "popToTop": [Function anonymous],
    "push": [Function anonymous],
    "removeListener": [Function removeListener],
    "replace": [Function anonymous],
    "reset": [Function anonymous],
    "setOptions": [Function setOptions],
    "setParams": [Function anonymous],
  },
  "route": Object {
    "key": "Sign Up-q-zIoH0VCp",
    "name": "Sign Up",
    "params": undefined,
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a problem with Firebase. The issue you are having is with accessing the navigation reference from within an arrow function that is executed after the promise returns. The scope of `this` is different from within that arrow function.

To get around situations like this React Navigation [has a solution](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/) where you can define a function to call navigate directly.

```
import { createNavigationContainerRef } from '@react-navigation/native';

export const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef()

export function navigate(name, params) {
  if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
    navigationRef.navigate(name, params);
  }
}
```

Then you can simply import `navigate` and use it like so.

```
navigate('ExtendedRegisteration');
```

The reason this isn't commonly used everywhere is because it can become problematic when you have complex nested routes, and it also doesn't give you access to other navigation methods, but for situations like yours it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

'this' means context and it is most funny thing in react.
Try console.log(this.props) to check whether the props in firebase then is same as the other example.
Since the this was called from inside the promise it could have change the 'this' context. It happens more than expected times.

You could try creating a function

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this._onUserCreation = this._onUserCreation.bind(this);
}

_onUserCreation=()=>{this.props.navigation.navigate('ExtendedRegisteration')};

//SignUp.js
signUpHandler = () => {
        if (this.state.email == '' || this.state.password == '') {
            alert("Email or Password is empty.")
        }
        else {
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
                .then(() => this._onUserCreation())
                .catch(error => { alert(error.message) });
        }
    }
```

Comment: No luck with this. I still got the same problem. Why did we create a separate function for navigation here though?

Comment: Seperate function is created to bind the context. It is how my issue was solved. What did console.log(this.props) showed?

Comment: I've added the output in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

Pass this as a parameter from wherever you invoke the signup function and use that parameter in place of this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you unmount FirebaseRecaptcha.FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal before you navigate